# Having trouble evaluating a spacetime integral, using Feynman parameterization and wick rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, integration, wick-rotation

> I am trying to evaluate the following integral,
>   $$\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^2k^2} \left(\frac{\mu}{4M} \right)^2 \frac{k^4 + \frac{1}{3}\vec{k}(k^2 - 2Mk_0)}{(k^4 - 4m^2k_0^2)(k^2 - 2Mk_0)} .$$

My general understanding of evaluating an integral in Minkowski space is: First determine whether the integral needs some sort of initial manipulation to get it in a more friendly form. Two, either use an integral table or go the more manual route using Wick rotation to transform the integral from 4D Minkowski space to standard 4D euclidean space.

I have tried several ideas...

1st: Break up the integral into two main integrals first

$\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^2k^2} \left(\frac{\mu}{4M} \right)^2 [ \frac{k^4}{(k^4 - 4m^2k_0^2)(k^2 - 2Mk_0)}  + \frac{\frac{1}{3}\vec{k}(k^2 - 2Mk_0)}{(k^4 - 4m^2k_0^2)(k^2 - 2Mk_0)} ]$

$\Rightarrow \int d^4k  \frac{k^2}{(k^4 - 4m^2k_0^2)(k^2 - 2Mk_0)}  + \int d^4k\frac{\frac{1}{3}\vec{k}}{k^2(k^4 - 4m^2k_0^2)} $

From this point I try and use Feynman parameterization separately on both integrals.

2nd: Attack the whole integral, and begin by application of Feynman parameterization.

In both of these methods I am struggling with the $k_0$ term. There is a book written by Klauber titled, "Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory." In this book, there is a table of space-time integrals. This table does not have a spacetime integral that has single components of the four momentum. The integrals either have amplitudes of four momentum or scalar products of four momentum. This has me thinking three ideas.

The first being, in some way or another I need to algebraically remove the $k_0$ component. This way I can use the tables.

Two, I am out of luck using the provided spacetime integral table, and proceed the more manual approach. Use Wick rotation and begin hammering away at the integral. Possibly dusting off my contour integration techniques.

Three, I am still very much naive in the ways of evaluating these integrals and I am missing something.

My guess is that it will be some combination of 2 and 3.

I will update as I progress through this adventure :) Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I know it's physics based, (and cross posting is not on) , but have you considered MathSE, in that someone there might just absolutely love using fancy substitutions on arcane "standard" integrals? Or splitting up it into  math and physics if that is possible.

Comment: @CountTo10 I have not thought about asking MathSE. I am not famillar with protocol of migrating questions. Or would I simply just ask this question again over at the MathSE?